# Apache2.4 +AEM+HEAD

Tags: caching, header, aem, cache-control, apache2.4

Apache2.4 cache control header is missing when the content is not cached, is it because the request is HEAD instead of GET , this behavior was different on 2.2  were head and post was having cache control header.

```
curl  -I https://localhost/test.html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 14 Nov 2020 00:10:39 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en


 curl  -I https://localhost/test.html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 14 Nov 2020 00:25:24 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
Last-Modified: Sat, 14 Nov 2020 00:25:19 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 206004
Expires: Sun, 15 Nov 2020 00:25:24 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Language: en
```

Comment: Did you only update the Apache version or the dispatcher module as well? By default, the dispatcher just forwards all the headers.

Comment: dispatcher also updated from 4.2.2 to 4.3.3

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: Not yet , I am not sure if this is Apache or Dispatcher , only happens when using HEAD , if we use GET ,content is pulled from AEM to Apache and headers works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Default behavior on Apache2.4 , when data is stored inside apache then header info is displayed or else not.